# Why does Windows update show updates for Office products that have been deleted?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, microsoft-office-2007

My Windows 7 system came with "trial" versions of Office (2007) installed.  I removed them (with add/remove programs).  However, whenever I run Windows Update it still shows updates needed for those Office products.  Why?  What do I do to stop this?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you need to get MS Office (any version), and install it. [I'm assuming you're using OpenOffice. Or something else? If you're already using MSOffice, which version of MSOffice?]

You can ignore the errors by "[hiding the updates](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/20a6c7df-5a58-4ebc-93aa-97246354ebd2)".

You can do this by right-clicking the update, and then clicking "Hide Update".

Comment: As you guessed, I'm using OpenOffice; OO is more than adequate for my needs, so I don't want to get MS-Office, so installing it is an undesirable (and expensive, IMO) solution.  I had already considered hiding the updates, but figured that future Office updates would just have to be hidden also, and I want to avoid that ongoing cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Windows update

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistawu/thread/0c631521-768b-4057-982c-c7108bdadeb3

Comment: Unfortunately, this was no help.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the trial left some registry keys, etc which could be telling windows to look for updates.

I did find this online (has instructions and a app to download)

http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/01/03/microsoft-office-2007-complete-registry-removal-and-deletion-uninstaller/

Which looks like it could weed them out. **I haven't personally tried it**, as I have - and use - Office (so don't want to go through removing and installing it).

The other option is to just hide the updates as recommended by Muntoo.

Comment: According to the write up about it, the script is made for use only when you want to re-install Office, so it's not useful in my situation.

Comment: But it could get rid of the traces of it you need gone... Just don't follow the steps to re-install it.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830335), this could be caused by leftover components from previously installed software, or software still on your PC which has shared components or dependencies with the Office components.

If they are security updates, I would recommend installing them because if those components remain on your system, you may be exposed to those vulnerabilities.

If they are recommended updates that just provide performance/bug fixes you can safely hide the update by right clicking on it. Installing these as well wouldn't hurt though.

Comment: So how do you prevent this behavior?  Can you provide specific instructions?  Until this answer has that information,I feel obligated to indicate this answer isn't helpful by voting.

Comment: @Ramhound My answer, as well as Microsoft's, implies that this is intended behavior and there is nothing you can do about it. It is by design and therefore is not an "issue" that needs a fix. 

I was not aware that I had to spell out every minor implication in order for my answer to be useful.

Comment: I have explained my vote by leaving a comment.  I really don't have anything else to say.